Why isn't the moment of inertia the rotational analog of INERTIA?
I've thought that both mass and the moment of inertia measure an object's inertia, one being in translational motion and the other in rotational motion. That has made complete sense to me, but in my textbook the definitions of inertia and moment of inertia are very close to one another, "Inertia" being the resistance of an object to accelerate linearly and "Moment of Inertia" being the resistance of an object to accelerate rotationally.
It makes it look like moment of inertia should be the rotational analog of inertia and not mass. I find myself confused, what is the difference between inertia and moment of inertia, and how does mass relate to both?

How would you describe the difference between inertia and mass (inertial mass, that is, not gravitational mass) ?

Mass is a measure of inertia.


but in my textbook the definitions of inertia and moment of inertia
are very close to one another

They are. The term "moment" is synonymous with the term "torque" which is is required for angular acceleration. Thus the term moment of inertia is the resistance to angular acceleration due to torque.

It makes it look like moment of inertia should be the rotational
analog of inertia and not mass.

That's correct. Because inertia is only one measure of mass, another being gravitational mass. So while moment of inertia is substituted for the mass in Newton's second law as applied to angular acceleration, it is done so only due to the inertial measure of mass, and not the gravitational measure of mass.
Hope this helps.

There are two aspects of mass. One is inertia, defined by Newton's Second Law, $F=ma$. The other is gravitational mass, defined by Newton's law of gravity, $F=\dfrac{G m_1 m_2}{r^2}$. They are the same in relativity, this is called equivalence principle. So, you can say moment of inertia is "rotational" mass, but it's more accurate to say it's rotational inertia because it doesn't generate gravitational field.

The equation for linear momentum is $m \times v$.
THe equation for angular momentum is $i \times \omega$.
Notice the similarity between the two form. The measure of the inertia in the linear case is simply the mass. The measure of the inertia in the rotational case is $I$. In the simple case of a mass m connected to a massless rod that pivots around a point at distance r from the mass, the moment of inertia is $I = mr^2$. This rotational measure of inertia or equivalently the "moment of inertia" takes both the mass and its distance from the pivot into account. Since $\omega = v/r$ we can rewrite the angular momentum $I \times \omega$ as $mr^2 \times v/r = mvr$. This only differs from linear case by having a term for the rotational radius.
